How to make the design responsive with two different backgrounds using tailwind css
I am taking this picture from the Figma design, I need to map this design to react with tailwind CSS pixel-perfect 100%.
Macbook Pro 16 inch has 1728px width but I need to make the content center with a customized container of 1300px width. So when it opens on a wider screen, the content should be in a center container of width 1300 px and the background should be extended to white space on both sides.
Some Instructions:

Background should span the entire viewport width: This means the background should stretch to the full width of the browser window, regardless of the screen size
Content container should have a max-width: The content inside a central container should not exceed 1300px, ensuring it doesn't stretch too wide on large screens for better readability and layout control
Center the content container: To keep the container centered within the viewport when the screen width is larger than 1300px

What is the best approach to do this?


Try setting the main content width to 90% and do the margin: 0 auto; it will be at the centre giving some whitespace from left and right.

Why not create a container of 1300 px and center it using the tailwind config?
Just give this concept from Gemini and GPT. Is this a good one?

How to manage two different backgrounds that also extended to extra space from both sides?
